# Batch script to connect via SSH, execute a command and pass the results to an OUTPUT file

Tags: batch-file, output

I realize the query is simple and there are a lot of similar topics around the internet, but for some reason I cannot make this work and I am at its very end.

This is the scenario. A batch script will connect (using putty link) to a Host. It will execute a command (like check Host version). The script will bring the output to a file.

So far I was able to configure most of it - my script uses a pool - source file that holds the IPs, to read the Hosts it needs to connect to; it connects to the hosts; executes the check version command and it saves the result to a file.
However, the result has a bad format and I am not able to bring the format I would like to see in the output file.

This is my code:

```
:Var
set out=E:\output.txt
set src=E:\servers.txt
set ver=cat /etc/*-release
set creds=-l root -pw root
set host=hostname
:Cond
for /f %%i in (%src%) do call :Cmd %%i
:Cmd
plink -ssh %1 %creds% %host%
plink -ssh %1 %creds% %ver%
echo %1 is %ver% >> %out%
```

The result is something like this:

```
server01Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 Beta (Tikanga)
server02Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 Beta (Tikanga)
```

So I would like to make it properly formatted, for example:

```
server01 OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 Beta (Tikanga)
server02 OS:Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 Beta (Tikanga)
```

Or even to be able to truncate the output of the command that was ran at the host and display only part of it like "Red Hat" only for example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling :Cmd once and not returning.
And if you did return from :Cmd you would fall right into it.
you need to end :Cmd with
goto :eof

Then you need to put another
goto :eof (or some goto)
before :Cmd so that you don't fall into it.

How do you want the output to look?  If you always want the first 2 tokens use a FOR statement.

Comment: Hi RGuggisberg

Thanks for the hints. I will make the change.
As for the result, I would like to achieve the following output:

server01 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.7 Beta
server02 Ubuntu
server03 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6

So this means <server><tab><version>. I also found myself in quite a problem trying to embed <tab> in the script, so if this is not possible, I would at least like to make sure there are spaces between <server> and <version>.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to solve your problem on the linux side, ie, change the script so it displays exactly what you want. For example you can execute the following command:

```
(hostname;echo -e "\tOS:";cat /etc/issue)|sed '{:q;N;s/\n//g;t q}'
```

this executes hostname, echoes a tab character and "OS:", and displays the /etc/issue (You can use /etc/*-release too). Finally all newlines are removed from the result using sed. (you can also use `tr "\n" ""`)

If you want to execute this using plink, you need to make sure to properly escape characters like `|` in the batch file. I don't have a windows machine close but it might look like this:

```
plink -ssh %1 %creds% ^(hostname;echo -e "\tOS:";cat /etc/issue^)^|sed '{:q;N;s/\n//g;t q}'
```

I am not sure I properly escaped it. It would be easier to store the command in a file, and then execute it. You could even upload the script using scp, execute and delete it.